# Create a contact in people in Outlook 2016

Tags: macos, ms-office

In Mail for Mac I can create a contact directly from an email message. In Outlook 2016 for Mac how can I do that as well? Seems like email has made more advances that Outlook has.

Answer (score 1):

Message → Sender → Add to People

[image]